# Strange Rails Routing behaviour: two ids swapped around in nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following routing set up in my app (forms belong to a site):

```
map.resources :sites do |site| 
 site.resources :forms
end
```

However, when I try to go to a path for edit (or such) for a form using the helpers (e.g.

```
edit_site_form_path(form)
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Show', [:site, form] %>
```

my URLs are coming out with the ID's swapped over ( /sites/5/forms/1 ) where 5 is the form Id, and 1 is the site id.  This is from the page /sites/1.

Help(?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `edit_site_form_path` method has to have two parameters, the site_id and the form_id. So  in your example you are only passing in the form_id. The first parameter is what ever model comes first in the method, in this case it is `site`. The second parameter is the form_id.

A revamped path method might look like this

```
 edit_site_form_path(form.site, form)
```

(assuming you have a model `Form` which `belongs_to :site`)

Comment: Bingo - I think I love you, this has been driving me nuts ;)