# Why are id's from nested route switched around?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a nested resource under my admin namespace:
The `admin/topic/comments_controller.rb` is a resource under `admin/topics_controller.rb`.

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :topics do
      resources :comments, :controller => "topic/comments"
    end
  end
```

gives me this delete route:

`DELETE

/admin/topics/:topic_id/comments/:id(.:format)

admin/topic/comments#destroy`

And I am creating a link to destroy comments, like the following:

`# comment = @topic.comment.first

<%= link_to "Destroy", [:admin, comment], :method => :delete %>`

produces the following route:

`/admin/topics/165/comments/11`

All seems correct, except that the two ids are swapped around. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found out that this is a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761360/strange-rails-routing-behaviour-with-nested-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the name_route instead :

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", admin_topic_comment_path(@topic, comment), :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: that will generate `undefined method admin_topic_topic_comment_path` error

Comment: thanks, so I guess the `[]` routing can't achieve everything alone. Named routes helper methods are needed after all.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= link_to 'Destroy', :action => 'destroy', :id => comment.id, :method => :delete %>`

or if you use RESTFUL routes:

`<%= link_to 'Destroy', delete_comment(:id => comment.id), :method => :delete %>`

When working with namespaced controllers and routes, you have to use namespaced models in order for the `link_to` helper to function properly.

e.g., in app/models/admin/comment.rb

```
class Admin::Comment < Comment   
end
```